# Parse a URL to extract all the GET variables in the URL

Tags: php, url, get

How can I parse the current url to get all the GET variables from it. Although there is a function by the name of

```
HTTP_GET_VARS
```

But the documentation says it is deprecated so I do not want to use that. I want to do something like this, if I have a url as

```
www.example.com/variables.php?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3
```

I want to extract all the GET variable in an array vars such that I have the name of the variable as well it's value in the url so tha I can use them while building a different url as

```
www.example.com/new_variables.php?vars[var_name]=vars[var_value]
```

I can go through all the variables in a for loop and incrementally build the url. What I mean is that using GET I have to see if the value is set for each of the variables that I expecting, but what I want is to get the list of all the GET variables which are set. My ulr can contain 3-4 variable which may not be set all the time. I don't want to check if all 4 are set at any point of time, I just want to filter my query based on whichever parameters are set.

Answer (score 6):

Use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

e.g.

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $output);
```

*EDIT*: And you can use its reverse friend [http_build_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-str.php) to do the opposite

Answer (score 1):

The `$HTTP_GET_VARS` variable is marked as deprecated because the newer `$_GET` variable was introduced. That's the one you should use. It contains all paramters from the query string in an associative array, e.g. `$_GET['var1']` would be 1 in your case.

If you want to construct the new URL with all GET parameters, you could loop over them, or you could just copy the current query string:

```
$new_url = "new_variables.php?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```